# add output of %link directive to variable?

Tags: .net, nhaml

In my master a partial _styles is loaded.
In this _styles there is a ^var styles = ""
Now in all my views or partials I can say var styles = styles+"another style"

Normally a style is defined as

```
%link{ href="../../content/css/partial.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" }
```

How can I append the output of the %link directive to the styles variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a [post](http://dnagir.blogspot.com/2009/07/nhaml-scripts-and-styles-code-block.html) about adding styles and links with the NHAML.
This should do all job for you.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know these existed: Html.Content().EmitCss(css)
That should answer my question

Comment: These really DO NOT exist. These are my extension methods to siplify things on the view.

Comment: In that case, how do you make sure the intendation of your output is correct?

Comment: NHAML indents the output, not me. Only one thing is that there will be empty lines if there are no CSS/JS files included.  But I do not see how it can be an issue.